# Why is a Big Mac called 巨无霸 (jùwúbà)?

Tags: translation, food

[image: McDonald's Big Mac box with 巨无霸 written on it]

**Question**: Why is a Big Mac called [巨无霸](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B7%A8%E6%97%A0%E9%9C%B8) (jùwúbà)?

Translating the individual hanzi:

- [巨](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B7%A8) (jù) = huge
- [无](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%97%A0) (wú) = without
- [霸](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9C%B8) (bà) = tyrant; lord

So 巨 seems reasonable (essentially the "big" part of "Big Mac"), but the rest doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B7%A8%E6%97%A0%E9%9C%B8/1226195

巨无霸 (巨毋霸) was a historical character who was famous for being a giant. Later people commonly use '巨无霸' as a nickname for something that is 'giant size'. For example, compare to modern dragonfly's modest 1-4 inches length, the dragonfly- like Meganeuropsis was no doubt a 'giant'(巨无霸) with it's 18 inches long body

Meganeuropsis- 青蜓中的**巨无霸** (**giant** among dragonflies)

[image: Meganeuropsis]

巨无霸 is not a translation of 'Big Mac', it is a Chinese name for 'Big Mac' . Someone gave 'Big Mac' this Chinese name because the selling point of 'Big Mac' is "it is BIG"

*'Big Mac' is 'giant' among hamburgers*

Answer (score 0):

巨无霸 means big, no other can compare. It really fits the Big Mac's character.

Answer (score 0):

Big Mac=巨无霸
BROCKEN GIGANT=巨无霸
Maximals=巨无霸(《Transfomers :Beast War》）